# C++ While Loop Break

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, break, repeat

My goal is to create a C++ program that executes a chunk of code repeatedly until the user enters in an appropriate value and does so with the use of a while loop. My code is just repeating over and over and even if I input a "0" it still repeats the chunk of code in the loop.

Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    bool repeat = true;
    while (repeat = true)
    {
        cout << "Please select an option." << endl;
        cout << "[1] Continue Program" << endl;
        cout << "[0] Terminate Program" << endl;
        cout << "---------------------" << endl;

        repeat = false;

        cin >> num;
        cout << endl;

        if (num = 1)
        {
            repeat = true;
            //execute program
        }
        else if (num = 0)
            repeat = false;
        else
            cout << "Please enter an appropriate value.";
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What did you notice, when stepping through your program line by line using a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (repeat = true)
```

In the `while` condition, you are using the assignment operator `=`, not equality `==`.

It's valid C++ syntax, but not what you expected. `repeat` is assigned to `true`, so the condition is always true.

The same error exists in `if (num = 1)` and `else if (num = 0)`.

Comment: Switch all warnings on and listen to them?

Comment: This is the correct answer, and is more descriptive than the other.

Comment: Thank you! I am pretty new to programming, so I appreciate the help!

Comment: @MichaelBarneyJr As πάντα ῥεῖ said, some compiler may give you a warning on this, check if your compiler is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
  while (repeat = true)
                ^^
```

is one of your problems:

```
  while (repeat == true)
                ^^
```

With an assignment, the condition always evaluates to a true.

Some people advocate using **[Yoda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076689/c-styleguide-why-to-have-non-lvalues-on-the-left-side)** to avoid these typos. Another way is to simply compile your program with the highest warning levels:

```
-Wall
```

Comment: Switch all warnings on and listen to them?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Indeed or alternatively, play Yoda! ;-)

Comment: Aww, greenish color I spot in my face ;-) ...

Comment: Best answer, this is

Answer (score 2):

Check your operators. You're using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` in your while and if arguments.